# Animated decrease of a UILabel's width doesn't get displayed

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

I'm trying to decrease the width of a UILabel inside an animation, but the width changes instantly without any animation! If I increase the width, everything works fine and you can see the animation.

Here is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear 
                 animations:^ (void){
                       CGRect theNewFrame      = self.titleLabel.frame;
                       theNewFrame.size.width -= 50.0; 
                       self.titleLabel.frame   = theNewFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

So if I change

```
theNewFrame.size.width -= 50.0;
```

to

```
theNewFrame.size.width += 50.0;
```

you can watch the label increasing. But decreasing the width wont work!

I don't have any explanation for this behavior. Is this a bug?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: is your `titleLabel` width by any chance less then 50?

Comment: did you get any solution for this? i'm also stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the label's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeCenter` before starting the animation.

```
self.titleLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: I know this is an old topic but you will see what's wrong if the UILabel has a background -- it looks like it doesn't really animate